# How to have not_analyzed for all new indexes by default?

Tags: elasticsearch

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448431/how-to-set-index-not-analyzed-globally-for-elastic-search) that I can use [`dynamic_template`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) to set string fields to `not_analyzed` for **new fields in a specific new index**.

Is there a way to have this setting applied **globally** - i.e. having the property `not_analyzed` set for any string field in any new index? (without the need to set it for each new index)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by creating an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) on `*` with a [`_default_` mapping type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/default-mapping.html) and [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/global -d '{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can create any document in any new index and the all string fields will be `not_analyzed`

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dummy_index/dummy_type/1 -d '{"name": "dummy"}'
```

If you check the `dummy_type` mapping type of the newly created `dummy_index`, you'll see that the `name` field will be `not_analyzed`

Comment: How to do this in brand new elastic search on startup in java client?

Comment: @JayaAnanthram if you search for `[elasticsearch] java mapping` you'll find plenty of answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552845/configure-elasticsearch-mapping-with-java-api

Comment: Ah this is what exactly I am looking for.. Bingo!