# How to have a mapping to not_analyze some fields for all indexes and types by default

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I understand how to build a mapping for any index and type. But, I want to have a field `my_field_1` and `my_field_2`  which will not be analyzed for **all the indexes and types** that will be created in future.

```
PUT /address_index
{
    "mappings":{
    "address":{
     "properties":{
      "state":{
       "type":"string",
       "fields":{
        "raw":{
            "type":"string",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
}
```

I also saw in one of the links on how to do for all the [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448941/how-to-have-not-analyzed-for-all-new-indexes-by-default). But, I am unable to add it for just the fields mentioned above.

I will be implementing this in Java. However, just DSL JSON would be good headstart.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) with a pattern of "*" meaning it will apply to all indices you create in the future and defining this mapping in there.

```json
PUT 127.0.0.1:9200/_template/stacktest
{
    "template": "*",
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "address": {
            "properties": {
                "state": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now you can create an index with any name and this mapping will apply to it.

```
PUT 127.0.0.1:9200/testindex/
```

---

```json
GET 127.0.0.1:9200/testindex/_mapping

{
    "testindex": {
        "mappings": {
            "address": {
                "properties": {
                    "state": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the *index: not_analyzed* part was transformed into the *keyword* datatype, as string has been deprecated. You should use [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/text.html) and [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/keyword.html) if you are on version 5.x.

---

**Edit to address your comments**

To adapt this to the specific two fields mentioned by you, the following request would create the template:

```json
{
    "template": "*",
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "properties": {
                "my_field_1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "my_field_2": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you now index a document into a new index, those two fields will be not analyzed **for any type of document**, any other string fields will be analyzed, which is the way I understood your original question.

```json
PUT 127.0.0.1:9200/testindex/address
{
    "my_field_1": "this is not_analyzed",
    "my_field_2": "this is not_analyzed either",
    "other_field": "this however is analyzed"
}

PUT 127.0.0.1:9200/testindex/differenttype
{
    "my_field_1": "this is not_analyzed",
    "my_field_2": "this is not_analyzed either",
    "other_field": "this however is analyzed"
}
```

Now check the mapping and notice the difference:

```json
    {
    "testindex": {
        "mappings": {
            "differenttype": {
                "properties": {
                    "my_field_1": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "my_field_2": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "other_field": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "address": {
                "properties": {
                    "my_field_1": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "my_field_2": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "other_field": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "_default_": {
                "properties": {
                    "my_field_1": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "my_field_2": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I donot want it for all the fields , i want to do only for specific feilds mentioned in my question that is "my_field1" and "my_field2"

Comment: what are u saying is basically what has been said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448941/how-to-have-not-analyzed-for-all-new-indexes-by-default and mentioned in my question in the "strings" hyperlink.

Comment: Actually what I am saying differs from the link that you mention in your question (which I looked at before answering) since it only defines the mapping for a specific field (**state** in this case) - not for all strings. I will add to the answer to illustrate the difference.

Comment: I was stupid and forgot the obvious solution, I have edited my answer again, so that it now fully addresses your issue as I understand it.

Comment: Abishek: Did the proposed answer address your question? If so, would you mind accepting the answer? If not, could you please add a brief comment what is missing - to my understanding this offers the functionality you enquired about?